# Scala. The best way to unwrap Option[Future[T]]

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Sometimes, I have a `Option[Future[T]]` val. And I want to deal with it:

```
do.something /* Option[A] here */ map { v => // v is of type A here
    doComplexCalculation(v) // it returns Future[T]
} map { v => // I want to get T here, after future becomes resolved. 
             // But here is Future[T] and I shoud do that:
    v map { v => // v is of type T here.

    }
}
```

The bad thing, from my point of view, is increasing of nesting level. I want to have more flat code :) The one of techinc, that I have found, is:

```
do.something /* Option[A] here */ map { v => // v is of type A here
    doComplexCalculation(v) // it returns Future[T]
} getOrElse {
    Future.failed(/* And I should pass Throwable here */)
} map { v => // v is of type T here

}
```

Could you show me a better way to do this? Things, that I don't like in my solution:

1. I should create failed Future by hand
2. I should create `Throwable` by hand

Comment: If that's the case don't use `Option`. Just `Future[T]` seems to be enough. Seems that if `Option` is `None`, you will react by returning a failed `Future`. So this extra level of inception (`Option` of `Future`) is unnecessary.

Comment: I can not change `do.something`. But thank you, I will think about it in my new code.

Answer (score 0):

why does your `do.something` return an Option to begin with?
If you want to fail in case of None, why doesn't do.something just throw or, perhaps, return a `Try`? 
Then you could just do

```
doComplexCalculation(do.something.get).map { v: T => 
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is not acceptable, because `do.something` could be long-chained code, e.g.: something.map {} map {} map {} map(doComplexCalculation)

Answer (score 0):

I think that following code is the best choice in your case

```
def doSomething[A](): Option[A] = ???
def complexCalculation[T](): Future[T] = ???

def someMethod() = {
  val resOption = doSomething()
  resOption match{
    case Some(res) =>{
      complexCalculation() map{ result =>
        println("Future successfully resolved so print res=" + res.toString)
      }
    }
    case None => println("doSomething returned None")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your participation, but this is no acceptable, because it has a same disadvantages: increasing the nesteding level. IMO, my second example is better.